# Как обратиться к конкретному the_title() Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, плагин

Делаю Хуук для WordPress, однако он изменяет еще и другие значение на странице, которые вытягиваються функцией `the_title();`
Как вытащить и изменить только тот`the_title()` который в `<h6 class="post_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h6>`
П.С. Задача- изменение `the_title()` конкретного поста. Однако в навигации, ета функция используеться так же. Когда делаю Хуук на изменение поста к функции `the_title()`( которой вынимаеться название поста ), то все меню принимает значение, которое ставиться на место `the_title()` поста ( так как там в меню название страниц так же извлекаются функицией `the_title()`).
Мой Хуук:

```
add_filter('the_title','add_h1_on_page');
function add_h1_on_page($title){
  $seo_post_type = woo_com_check();
  if(!empty($seo_post_type)){
    return  get_post_meta($seo_post_type->ID,'timworld_seo_h1', true);
  }
  return $title;
}
```

Кусок кода в котором лежит название поста:

```
<div class="slider_data">
                <a href=""...>...</a>
                <h6 class="post_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то вы сами себя перехитрили. Зачем такие сложности с хуками, если можно просто написать свою функцию, которая будет выводить тот заголовок, который вам нужен?

```
function my_title($title) {
  $seo_post_type = woo_com_check();
  if(!empty($seo_post_type)){
    return  get_post_meta($seo_post_type->ID,'timworld_seo_h1', true);
  }
  return $title;
}
```

И далее в разметке:

```
<div class="slider_data">
    <a href="">...</a>
    <?php $title = get_the_title(); ?>
    <h6 class="post_title"><?php echo my_title($title); ?></h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Угу, уже сделал, пасиб)